# Cannot get my first OpenCL program to work

Tags: opencl

I am trying to set up an OpenCL environment on my Windows 7-64 bit operating system, in order to be able to GPU program on my ATI Radeon HD 5450 for parallel computing purposes. I have Visual Studio 2015 and I downloaded AMD APP SDK v3.0 which supports OpenCL 2.0 ... Now I am trying to execute a simple program for vector addition:

```
#define CL_USE_DEPRECATED_OPENCL_2_0_APIS
#include <CL/cl.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std; 

int main() {
    //get all platforms (drivers)
    std::vector<cl::Platform> all_platforms;
    cl::Platform::get(&all_platforms);
    if (all_platforms.size() == 0) {
        std::cout << " No platforms found. Check OpenCL installation!\n";
        exit(1);
    }
    cl::Platform default_platform = all_platforms[0];
    std::cout << "Using platform: " <<default_platform.getInfo<CL_PLATFORM_NAME>() << "\n";

     //get default device of the default platform
    std::vector<cl::Device> all_devices;
    default_platform.getDevices(CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, &all_devices);
    if (all_devices.size() == 0) {
        std::cout << " No devices found. Check OpenCL installation!\n";
        exit(1);
    }
    cl::Device default_device = all_devices[0];
    std::cout << "Using device: " << default_device.getInfo<CL_DEVICE_NAME>() << "\n";


    cl::Context context({ default_device });

    cl::Program::Sources sources;

// kernel calculates for each element C=A+B
std::string kernel_code =
    "   void kernel simple_add(global const int* A, global const int* B, global int* C){       "
    "       C[get_global_id(0)]=A[get_global_id(0)]+B[get_global_id(0)];                 "
    "   }                                                                               ";
sources.push_back({ kernel_code.c_str(),kernel_code.length() });

cl::Program program(context, sources);
if (program.build({ default_device }) != CL_SUCCESS) {
    std::cout << " Error building: " << program.getBuildInfo<CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG>(default_device) << "\n";
    exit(1);
}


// create buffers on the device
cl::Buffer buffer_A(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, sizeof(int) * 10);
cl::Buffer buffer_B(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, sizeof(int) * 10);
cl::Buffer buffer_C(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, sizeof(int) * 10);

int A[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
int B[] = { 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0 };

//create queue to which we will push commands for the device.
cl::CommandQueue queue(context, default_device);

//write arrays A and B to the device
queue.enqueueWriteBuffer(buffer_A, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(int) * 10, A);
queue.enqueueWriteBuffer(buffer_B, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(int) * 10, B);


//run the kernel
//cl::KernelFunctor simple_add(cl::Kernel(program, "simple_add"), queue, cl::NullRange, cl::NDRange(10), cl::NullRange);
//simple_add(buffer_A, buffer_B, buffer_C);

//alternative way to run the kernel
cl::Kernel kernel_add=cl::Kernel(program,"simple_add");
kernel_add.setArg(0,buffer_A);
kernel_add.setArg(1,buffer_B);
kernel_add.setArg(2,buffer_C);
queue.enqueueNDRangeKernel(kernel_add,cl::NullRange,cl::NDRange(10),cl::NullRange);
queue.finish();

int C[10];
//read result C from the device to array C
queue.enqueueReadBuffer(buffer_C, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(int) * 10, C);

std::cout << " result: \n";
for (int i = 0; i<10; i++) {
    std::cout << C[i] << " ";
}

return 0;
}
```

The program compiles correctly, and the code is supposed to be fine. It took it from http://simpleopencl.blogspot.de/2013/06/tutorial-simple-start-with-opencl-and-c.html . But when I execute the code, it stops on the second line and it seems that it cannot get any platform. Anyone have an idea about the reason? Thanks!

Comment: You have the SDK, but do you have the driver installed?

Comment: You mean the AMD APP SDK? I think yeah it is installed properly... I followed the installation instructions till the end

Comment: I mean the driver, not the SDK. Otherwise you will compile a binary that does not find any useful HW in your system.

Comment: I thought that the AMD APP SDK is actually the driver... What else you mean with the driver? for the Intel processor?

Comment: If you have a GPU the driver is what the GPU vendor provides to you. Is not a .h file or a .cpp file or something you need to link, and no, it is NOT the SDK. Windows has a default driver that is just letting you use the GPU without any extra features (OpenCL, HW encoding, etc...). WHen you install the dirver you allow the features to be exposed to the applications.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a PC with intel then your intel PC CPU is going to act as the host device. I strongly recommend installing the intel OpenCL drivers as well(if you are using intel). This issue could be either because you have installed the wrong and driver or due to the lack of the intel OpenCL driver.

If your CPU is also an AMD CPU please check for the right driver version, a driver mismatch could also lead to issues like this.

Also, I would recommend doing a dual boot to ubuntu, it's much easier to work with OpenCL in a Linux CLI fashion.

Comment: Well that seems quite logical... Indeed, I am on working on an Intel core. I downloaded the Intel OpenCl driver under this link <https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/opencl-drivers> . Now, do we need to do the linking one more time, indicating the libraries and so on on visual studio? Also, it s weird but there was no bin path added to the path environment variable... Is that normal?

Comment: I guess you need to add the bin onto path manually and yes you must link the library again in visual studio. But please check whether the driver that you have installed exactly matches with your processor model.

Comment: Try installing the Intel SDK for opencl, it contains all the drivers. That's what I did when I had to run my code on an Intel based cpu